# Uploading csv file using python to azure blob storage

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a csv file to a container. It is constantly giving me an error that says - Retry policy did not allow for a retry: , HTTP status code=Unknown, Exception=HTTPSConnectionPool

Here is my code -

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='myAccoutName', account_key='myAccountKey')
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name='test1', blob_name='pho.csv', file_path = 'C:\\Users\\A9Q5NZZ\\pho.csv')
```

I am new to Python so if you can answer with a simple language, that would be really helpful.

Forget uploading a CSV file, it doesn't even let me view existing blobs in an existing container! It gives the same 'Retry Policy' error for the below code -

```
container_name = 'test1'
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
```

I understand I've asked two questions, but I think the error is the same. Any help is appreciated. Again, since I am new to Python, an explanation/code with simpler terms would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `get_blob_to_path` you're using is for downloading blob to local. If you want to upload a local file to azure blob storage, you should use this method `block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name="",blob_name="",file_path="")`

The sample code works at my side:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='xxx', account_key='xxxx')
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name="mycontainier",blob_name="test2.csv",file_path="D:\\temp\\test2.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, here is the error I get - 

block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name="ekaur",blob_name="fleet.xlsx",file_path="C:\\Users\\A9Q5NZZ\\fleet.xlsx")


Client-Request-ID=d72393d4-ae1e-11e9-8580-88b111bc9f5c Retry policy did not allow for a retry: , HTTP status code=Unknown, Exception=HTTPConnectionPool(host='***%20.blob.core.windows.net', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ekaur/fleet.xlsx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001DBDB23CBE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')).

Comment: It also says this - 

> NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001DBDB249F98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

Comment: @ApoorvUpadhyaya, can you please try create a new storage account for testing purpose? I cannot figure out what's the reason in your side.

Comment: @ Ivan - It worked! Your first answer was correct. I was using jupyter notebook initially. But when i used Spyder using the code you provided with my credentials, it worked. This is strange. Perhaps there was some localhost issue?
Thanks a lot. I just hope blob storage is the right way to go for storing csvs :D

Comment: @ApoorvUpadhyaya, wow, so happy it's solved. And could you please help mark it as answer by following this [steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks.